# How to vertically center the text of a div no matter how many lines of the text

Tags: css

In the demo below, the first div appears to be vertically centered, but the second one doesn't.

How to CSS their common class to make them both centered? In other words, how do I vertically center the text of a div no matter how many lines of the text?

```css
.divs {
  /*position:absolute;*/
  font-size: 18px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  display: inline-block;
  background-color: #ffcc99;
  width: 140px;
  height: 80px;
  padding-top: 30px;
  /*padding-bottom: 30px;*/
  margin-top: 0;
  float: left;
  margin-left: 98.5px;
  word-wrap: break-word;
  vertical-align: middle;
  line-height: normal;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <div class="divs">1234567890</div>
  <div class="divs">12345678901234567890123</div>
</div>
```

Comment: What do you mean? http://jsfiddle.net/axw9ocne/

Comment: I think that's the one exception for which you still need tables, and then you set the vertical align property on the table cell.

Comment: https://css-tricks.com/vertically-center-multi-lined-text/

Answer (score 0):

```
<div>
<div class="divs">1234567890</div>  
<div class="divs">12345678901234567890123</div>
</div>
<style>
.divs{
     font-size: 18px;
     box-sizing: border-box;
    display: inline-block;
    background-color: #ffcc99;
    width:140px;
    height:80px;
    padding-top:30px;
    /*padding-bottom: 30px;*/
    margin-top:0;
    float:left;
    margin-left: 98.5px;
    word-wrap: break-word;
    text-align: center;
    line-height: normal; 
    width:inherit;
}
</style>
```

make text-align to center if you want it in middle Check this [link](http://jsfiddle.net/k36byLL1/)

Comment: The code makes two lines glued into one line by changing the div width. For my project, the width have to be fixed, but thanks anyway.